# Regular expression for matching 'A00000' format javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match a substring in the format 'A00000', 'B12342', 'W33344' from a string. Basically, first char is always a letter, and following five are numbers.

I have got two regular expressions for this, and it looks like both work correct:

```
str.match(/[A-Z]{1}\d{5}/)

str.match(/^[A-Z]\d{5}/)
```

Which is more strict, and is there anything better than these two? Thanks.

Comment: You can anchor the end as well to make it stricter still.

Comment: The first one finds it **anywhere** in the string. The second one finds it only if it is **at the begining** of the string. `{1}` is useless.

Comment: The `{1}` part does not change anything. But the `^` only filter for the expression if it is on the beginning of your other string... I don't know if you want that!

Comment: second one is anchored to the start of line. You said it's a part of a longer string, so probably you don't want this anchor.

Comment: It depends on whether `XYZA00000` should match or not.

Comment: Thanks guys! I have sorted it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match the pattern as part of a bigger string instead of just at the start or anywhere in the string and still make them "strict", you can use the boundary meta character:

```
/\b[A-Z]\d{5}\b/g
```

The `/g` modifier does a global search and finds more matches.

[Pattern explained](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=/%5Cb%5BA-Z%5D%5Cd%7B5%7D%5Cb/g)

**Example**

```
> 'A12345 B43221'.match(/\b[A-Z]\d{5}\b/g)
["A12345", "B43221"]
```

Comment: Your pattern is good, but if in one long string it matches two or more substrings, it picks up all of them. How could I restrict this pattern so that it picks up only one?

Comment: @KananFarzali Ehm, take the first match only? I can't really tell, because I don't know which match is better for you :) If only the first match, you can drop the `/g` modifier.

Comment: it doesn't really matter, they are exactly the same strings :) I removed /g, and it worked great. Thanks for that!